# Significato di "sbattere la testa contro il muro"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Buongiorno,

Cosa significa l'espressione sbattere la testa contro il muro? L'ho cercata nel dizionario ma non l'ho trovata.

Significa pensare duramente, sforzandosi eccessivamente, come in inglese I've banged my head on that one?

Grazie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dal [Dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/T/testa.shtml#58):

> **sbattere la testa contro il muro**
>
> Fig.: fare un'esperienza negativa per ostinazione, per cocciutaggine, per sopravalutazione delle proprie forze. Si dice di chi si ostina in una determinata idea o impresa e ne esce perdente.
>
> Var.: picchiare il capo contro il muro; sbattere il capo contro il muro; picchiare la testa contro il muro
>
> *Altro sign.*: Fig.: disperarsi, abbandonarsi a manifestazioni di dolore isteriche e violente.
> Psicanaliticamente, si può vedere in questo gesto la ricerca dell'autopunizione per un errore commesso.

Perciò non ha niente a che fare con l'espressione inglese "I've banged my head on that one".